# async task taking too long to do the job

Tags: android, android-asynctask, telnet

I need to send a command from device and `progressdialog` should display progress until command is finished.For this purpose i use `asynctask` in my application.
But it is taking much time to finish the command.

So, is there any way to set priority of asynctask to maximum?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well you can try this:

```
protected Void doInBackground() {
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
/* do the work */
}
```

Comment: Can you sense the different with or without this?

Comment: @Yeung for me, it made the process even slower

Comment: This will not help in case some other tasks are already running when you executed your task. Until thread scheduler gives your task some time to actually start executing, your `setPriority` will have no effect.

Answer (score 2):

You could also define your own custom timeout in case you don't want to keep the user waiting for an answer from the webservice past  definite time.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Android uses the background thread cgroup for all threads with priority `THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` or worse, and `THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` is 10 while `THREAD_PRIORITY_DEFAULT` is 0 and `THREAD_PRIORITY_FOREGROUND` is -2.

If you go for `THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND + THREAD_PRIORITY_MORE_FAVORABLE` (aka 9) your thread will be lifted out of the background cgroup with the 10% limitation, while not being important enough to interrupt your User Interface threads too often.

```
 protected final YourResult doInBackground(YourInputs... yis) {
        Process.setThreadPriority(THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND + THREAD_PRIORITY_MORE_FAVORABLE);
        ...
    }
```

but be aware that the underlying implementation may reuse the same Thread object for different tasks, for the next AsyncTask, or whatever. It seems that Android simply resets the priority after doInBackground() returns, though.
.